# Node.js LDAP auth with passport and passport-ldapauth

Tags: node.js, ldap, passport.js

Trying to create auth mechanism for LDAP in Node.js. I have a testing server and i can connect it in terminal with ldapsearch:

```
ldapsearch -LLL  -H "ldaps://my.custom.sample.server:636" 
-s sub -b "dc=custom,dc=sample,dc=server" -x 
-D "LDAP_LOGIN@custom.sample.server" 
-W uid=SOME_USER
```

I am asked for password for LDAP_LOGIN and I recieve response.

But when i try use passport with passport-ldapauth I get no response(not even badCredentialsError)

Here is my code:

```
var passport = require('passport');


var LdapStrategy = require('passport-ldapauth');

passport.use(new LdapStrategy({
    server: {
        url: "ldaps://my.custom.sample.server:636",
        bindDn: 'LDAP_LOGIN@custom.sample.server',
        bindCredentials: CONFIG('password'),
        searchBase: 'dc=custom,dc=sample,dc=server',
        searchFilter: '(uid={{username}})'
    }
}, function(err, res, req) {
    console.log(err, res, req);
    //done(null, profile);
}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
    done(null, obj);
});
```

Comment: Hi can you try changing bindDn to dc=custom,dc=sample,dc=server

Comment: If that fails, try changing bindDn to  cn=LDAP_LOGIN,dc=custom,dc=sample,dc=server

Comment: I tryed but still no response, but ldapsearch works allways well.

Comment: I temporarily switched to ldapjs wich works well in almost the same configuration, I wonder what I am doing wrong with passport...